# Viewing polyhedrals through the new 3D viewer QGIS 2.99 (3.0)

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

I've installed QGIS 2.99 to test its new features, particularly the 3D viewer, when I try the following I only see a square, not a 3D cube.

In PostGIS I make a square and extrude it

```
-- make a square
CREATE TABLE public.square1
(
    id serial,
    geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT square1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO public.square1 (geom)
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 0 100, 100 100, 100 0, 0 0)')) AS geom;
```

I add the following sql via the db manager and add as a layer.

```
SELECT 
ST_SetSRID(ST_Extrude(ST_Buffer(square1.geom, 0),0,0,10), 27700) AS geom
FROM Square1
```

But I only see 2D geometry, no 3D geometry.
I had to set a srid, QGIS would not allow no projection or ESPG:4326

I test the polyhedral for its volume, this is correct

```
ST_volume(ST_Extrude(ST_Buffer(square1.geom, 0),0,0,10) ) AS volume
FROM Square1
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Did you enable the 3d renderer ?
If not in each layer properties you have to go to the 3D View windows and check the box then set the appropriate parameters

[image]

Comment: I forgot that step! When it is enabled QGIS 2.99 crashes, I've reported it as a bug. Is there any other reason why a sql query via the database manager would cause this problem. I have checked the geometry, it is a polyhedral and the correct volume is calculated.

Comment: even using shapefile with z value the 3D viewer crash very often...

Comment: Do you by chance know any other kind of lightweight 3D viewers (that can work on Linux) that can directly be fed PostGIS polyhedrals to actualy visualize them?